# Knife upload completes but list is empty

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am just learning Chef and have been able to successfully setup the Knife SDK locally to list roles for my organization on manage.chef.io.  I can also upload cookbooks and it says it successfully uploads 4 cookbooks but if I try to list cookbooks the result is empty.

I installed the 4 cookbooks locally using "knife cookbook site".

What am I missing?

OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

After some help from the #chef IRC channel I eventually found chef-zero was being started by knife automatically and uploading the cookbooks to a local temporary server.  In the end I simply needed to add the following to my knife.rb file:

```
chef_zero.enabled        false
```

The documentation page (https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) specifies this config value should default to false.  Not sure why its not.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use below command as you are working on local mode for need to append such parameters

knife cookbook list -a -z

-a for all
-z for local mode